# How to get an Azure Active Directory access token for https://api.spaces.skype.com

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, skypedeveloper

I need to get an access token for the audience https://api.spaces.skype.com. I need to use the Azure Active Directory v1 endpoint. I dont see any corresponding API permission

[image]

In the Manifest there is the `requiredResourceAccess` section where resourceAppIds and scopes can be configured. How can I find the correct resource app id for https://api.spaces.skype.com?

Answer (score 2):

That API is an internal one used by the Teams client only. We do not allow non-Microsoft applications to access it.

The only supported API for Microsoft Teams is [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and our Bots API.

Comment: I cannot use the Microsoft Graph API, since it does not support adding guest users to Teams (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180474/adding-invited-guest-user-to-teams-seems-to-not-work-properly).

Comment: @halllo- Adding guest user is a two step process. First step is to send invitation for which you can use [Invitation Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0). And once user is invited to your AD you can add him/her using [Add Members Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT When I use Graph API to create the group with owners and members in a single POST and then PUT the team to it, then the guest user is added to the team, even if he/she has not yet redeemed the invitation.

Comment: I believe this is same experience from UI as well. If you add Guest user, it will start showing in members list even though invitation is not accepted. Please let us know if you observe different behaviour.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT When I attempt add a user later with  `graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(userToAdd)` then it does not add the user to the team members. This where the Teams UI behaves completely different.