# Microsoft Teams: Provide 'Edit in Teams' for Sharepoint Documents in Custom Tab

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, ms-wopi

We are writing a document organization system as a Custom Tab within Microsoft Teams and we are trying to replicate the 'Edit in Teams' option that´s provided by Microsoft Teams on the Files tab but it seems that we are unable to replicate the functionality. We are storing files within Sharepoint and have an edit URL, but we are unable to iframe this link due to CORS issues and can only open this link in a new browser. Does anyone have any thoughts on how we can open office documents within the teams client from a custom tab other than opening as a new window which means users have to keep switching in and out of Microsoft Teams.

By looking at what Microsoft teams is doing via the network requests, when you select ´Edit in Teams' it is getting hold of an  wacUrlEdit link which appears to be iframeable which for example begins with `https://euc-word-edit.officeapps.live.com/we/wordeditorframe.aspx?ui=en`, however we can´t get hold of this wacUrlEdit link  as it  generated using an access token from https://api.spaces.skype.com, which according to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4406395/bill-bliss-msft on [How to get an Azure Active Directory access token for https://api.spaces.skype.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070388/how-to-get-an-azure-active-directory-access-token-for-https-api-spaces-skype-c) isn´t publicly available, it´s only intended for the teams client. Fyi.. It also seems that Teams doesn´t IFrame this wacUrlEdit, but opens up a new url (at least in the web browser) via https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/docx/viewer/teams

I have read about WOPI host implementation, but this does seem like a lot of work to solve this and not totally sure this is the correct option considering these files are stored in Sharepoint Online.

Comment: https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/docx/viewer/teams navigates within the same frame, it doesn't open up a new URL. 

Do you need your own window, or would opening up the document inside Teams (that is, using the Teams viewer) do the trick for you?

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT - We've tried this out with the /docx/viewer/teams url. We can open this url into a new window from our custom tab, but if we try and invoke this from within the custom tab it does not work from within the custom tab's iframe. It feels like we need to be able to invoke this url from the parent  if we want this to work in the same way as it does from the files tab in teams, not from within our custom tab.  Is there a way we can open this url from the Teams SDK? We did have a look at the tasks, but this doesn't seem like the correct route.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT -  We´ve found out that we can use the executeDeepLink JavaScript SDK method and send in a url with the following structure. But have had to figure this out from what is happening on the files tab. This seems to work, but we´d prefer to be using something that is documented.

https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/{docxExtenstion}/viewer/teams/{encodedSharepointFileUrl}/?threadId={channelId}&baseUrl={encodedSharepointBaseUrl}&fileId={sharepointFileId}&ctx={files|new_file}&viewerAction=edit

Comment: We're changing the default open mode to be edit -- can't be specific about a date but should be in the next few months.