# How to generate a SkyeToken for Teams native APIs?

Tags: .net, api, graph, microsoft-teams

I am working on posting messages on Teams channels. I've been using the Graph APIs but I am facing a huge amount of throttling so I wanted to switch to the Native APIs used when posting a message through the Teams GUI.
These APIs work with a token called SkypeToken that I am trying to generate. I have seen threads like this
[Adding invited (guest) user to teams seems to not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180474/adding-invited-guest-user-to-teams-seems-to-not-work-properly/55100723#55100723)
talking about how to generate it but it seems that this no longer works as I am receiving a 404 not found on the endpoint https://api.teams.skype.com/beta/auth/skypetoken queried to get the token. Does anyone know what the new endpoint is or any other way to generate this token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging and following the Fiddler network trace when opening Teams on the web, I could find what the new URL to get the Skype token is.
Long story short, this Powershell code works fine https://github.com/sanderdewit/teams-module/blob/master/teams_v2.psm1 except that the API URL has changed. You can just change it with the new URL "https://authsvc.teams.microsoft.com/v1.0/authz" and you will get your SkypeToken.